# Нейронная сеть для дополнительной проверки программ

Tags: java, c, нейронные-сети

Занимаюсь своей дипломной работой, суть которой заключается в следующем: есть некое web-приложение на Java, которое представляет собой систему тестирования заданий (схожа с системой тестирования олимпиадных задач).

Подробнее об этом: пользователь заходит на сайт ему представлены список заданий(несложные программы на языке C, к примеру найти n член Фибоначчи и т.д.) и тестовый список входных и выходных данных для программы, все это загружается с БД. Пользователь решает задание и отправляет текст программы на сервер и там должна будет осуществляться проверка(компилятором gcc) этого задания.

Как сделать корректную проверку задания? Есть идея, запускать процесс gcc с заданием, присланным от пользователя, читать вывод компилятора в терминал, если там белиберда выдавать пользователю ошибка компиляции, если нет, то загружать как раз такие тестовые входные данные для программы и сверять с выходным и после этого выводить пользователю правильно решенная задача или нет. Но с этим есть проблема, пользователь же просто может написать `printf(...)` согласно тестовым данным без реализации алгоритма и ему придет ответ, что все правильно. Так вот может кто подскажет как можно исключить этого?

Мне говорили нужно нейронку поставить, то вообще что она из себя будет представлять и по каким параметрам она будет проверять программу?

Comment: Не понял, зачем тут нейронка и какие задачи она решает. Обычно в проверяющих системах есть несколько тестов и пользователю доступна только часть из них. Таким образом пользователь почти никогда не сможет сделать готовый вывод результатов без решения задачи непосредственно

Comment: Скорее я бы беспокоился о том, чтобы программа пользователя не делала ничего лишнего. не могла работать с фаловой системой или сетью, не могла подвесить всю систему целиком и так далее

Comment: А какими средствами можно реализовать эту безопасность?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще то нейронная сеть тут вообще не нужна. Просто делаете несколько повторяющихся тестов, например: найти n-ое число Фибоначчи - и так раз 50. Смухлевать здесь будет сложнее, чем написать подобную прогу. Ввод и вывод направить через файлы и сравнивать выходной файл пользователя с эталоном (данными в нем). Вот и все.